# Time complexity of while loop inside for loop

Tags: java, time-complexity

I'm writing an algorithm that needs to find the length of smallest subarray that its sum is larger than given k parameter.

This is the function I wrote so far:

```
    public static int smallestSub (int [] a, int k) {
        int currSum = a[0];
        int start = 0;
        int minLen = a.length + 1;
        int currLen = 1;
        
        for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
            currSum += a[i];
            currLen++;

            while (currSum - a[start] > k && start < i) {
                currSum -= a[start];
                start++;
                currLen--;
            }

            if (currSum > k) {
                minLen = Math.min(currLen, minLen);
            }
        }

        return minLen;
    }
```

My question is: is the complexity of this algorithm `O(n^2)`?
I'm asking since while loop depends on for loop.

Comment: I believe that the time complexity is `O(n logn)`. It is not `O(n^2)` because the `while` loop doesn't run `n` times as the `for` loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is the complexity of this algorithm is O(n^2)?

**TL;DR version:** No, it isn't. It is in fact `O(n)`.

**Long version:**

First, let us notice that `i` goes from `1` to `n` (I suppose `a.length` is what you call `n`).

The inner loop increments `start` until it reaches `i`, but it doesn't restart from `0`. Therefore, for each iteration of the outer loop, you start from a certain `start'` and you reach a certain `start''` (that is at most the current value of `i`). Notice that `start'` is equal to the `start''` of the *previous step*.

Let us call `delta_i` the difference `(start'' - start')_i`, i.e. the number of iterations of the `i`-th inner loop.

The cost of the algorithm is the number of **overall** iterations of the inner loop. This can be computed as:

```
Σ_(i=1)^n {delta_i} = delta_1 + ... + delta_n
                    = (start'' - start')_1 + ... + (start'' - start')_n
                    = start''_1 - start'_1 + ... + start''_n - start')_n
                    = -start'_1 + start''_n
```

The last step is because every `start'_i` is equal to the next `start'_(i+1)` (for instance, `start''_1 = start'_2`), so they can be simplified. But `start'_1 = 0`, so we end up with just `start''_n`, which is at most `n`.

Thus, the overall complexity is `O(n)`.